# Display templates written in html alter for loops

Tags: javascript, display-template

In a display template (a filter item template to be precise), I observe a weird behavior with for loops.

Let's say my template consists in:

```
    <div id="CustomRefinement">
<!--#_

for(var x=0;x<10;x++ ){

}
for(var y=0;y<10;y++){

}    

_#-->
    </div>
```

It's transformed like this:

```
for(var x=0;x<10;x++ ){

}
for(var y="0;y<10;y++){"

}
```

(notice the quotes in the **2nd** for loop)

However, if I add spaces like this :

```
    <div id="CustomRefinement">
<!--#_

for(var x=0 ; x < 10 ; x++ ){

}
for(var y=0 ; y < 10 ; y++){

}   

_#-->
    </div>
```

It's transformed as:

```
for(var x=0 ; x < 10 ; x++ ){

}
for(var y=0 ; y < 10 ; y++){

}
```

Is there any reason explaining this behavior? Is there any other subtility to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate this behaviour with

```
if(2<1){}
```

While **a space after <** runs fine

```
if(2< 1){}
```

**Looks like a bug with the < in the parser that extracts the javascript from the HTML comments**

Because

```
if(1>2){}
```

runs fine

#### *"Seattle, we have a problem"*

Your statement can be *duct-taped* by placing the value inside round brackets

```
for(var x=0;x<(10);x++){}
```

I presume the bug has to do with an incorrect Regular Expression